# How to Identify and Terminate a Specific Approval Workflow from Another Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, approval

I'm creating an approval workflow using Power Automate for SharePoint Online.

I would like the workflow to be closed when the user presses the "Cancel" button in PowerApps while waiting for the first approver to approve.
In order to do this, I think I need to create another Flow that will work when the "Cancel" button is pressed.

Is there any way to find the workflow that is pending?
I would be very grateful for any idea/pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the end users , we are not able to provide a button to cancel the flow run. There is an action called **terminate** action which will stop the running flow. However it is often used to stop the flow in the process for certain condition.

Only Flow owners will be able to stop a pending flow in Power Automate studio. End users cannot do that in a list or library where he/she triggers the flow.